# Ubuntu locks up after reboot with 2nd monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

- Install OS, updates, and apply Nvidia driver.
- Install several applications like Skype, Chrome, Dropbox, and
  HipChat.
- No problems.  Reboot, no problems.
- Connect 2nd monitor via HDMI, no problems.
- Reboot with 2nd monitor connected, and I get about 3 seconds of
  desktop time before everything because unresponsive.  KB, Touchpad,
  Bluetooth mouse.
- Disconnect 2nd monitor, no change.
- Reboot with no 2nd monitor, works.  Repeat, encounter same issue
  every time a reboot is done with 2nd monitor.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  I followed the guide below and I'm now using the 364.xx Nvidia drivers but have the same issue.  If a second monitor is connected by HDMI, when the system powers on, it locks up within seconds.  Also notice my panel is smaller along the top too.  If I connect the monitor after the system is up, I never have an issue.

Comment: Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/

Comment: Please tell me if it does, so I can add it to the list of issues.

Comment: It did not resolve it.

Comment: No effect at all?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Still locks up.